# What would be the best way to create a custom search for a list

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Just need some advice here. I have a list and i would like to create a custom search so that users can search easily .The list has some checkboxes,texts,date.I want the user also to search by date range e.g from date to End date.
Not sure if i would be able to  use SPD and Data view webpart to get this done ?
Would  XsltListViewWebPart do this?.
Any advices or hints would be welcome.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?  Are you looking to do a search or to just filter a single list?

Comment: SP 2010.Search and filter a single list

Answer (score 2):

When working with a single list in SP 2010, you should start by checking out the Metadata navigation settings from the List Settings apge.  The Key Filters feature allows you to do more advanced filtering.  All configuration, no coding needed.  Check it out before doing something custom and complicated.

Comment: Thanks you've always had alternatives.Will check that out.but if you have any resources online to point me to that woud be great

Comment: Thanks you've always had alternatives.Will i did try it and it did work well for most filters but the question i have though is that i want to add a filters to created date i.e startdate and enddate.Any ideas

Answer (score 1):

The most easiest I would find, is to use the Filter web parts connected to the Data View Web Part (or XSLT View), which at its turn would be customized via SPD (SharePoint Designer).

The advantage is that you could build more complex queries to filter upon (up to 10 filter criteria fields) and you could also (if filter web parts won't do it for you) use standard ASP.NET controls directly in the page bound to actual data (via SPDataSource controls directly in page, tied up to each of your fields you plan to filter after).

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius